# unable to download a web page using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Im having problems downloading a webpage using python requests library. code worked fine until it stopped working suddenly. here is the code:

```
import requests
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17'}
url = 'http://maya.tase.co.il/bursa/index.asp?view=search&group_first_level=1&company_group=3000&arg_comp=&srh_comp_lb=1349&srh_from=2013-2-2&srh_until=2013-2-12&srh_anaf=-1&srh_event=9999&is_urgent=0&srh_company_press='
r  = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent)
r.text
```

I get some kind of CRC related response:

> u'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nfunction
>   str_reverse(in_str) { return ((in_str.split("")).reverse()).join("");
>   }\r\nfunction test(){var table = "00000000 77073096 EE0E612C 990951BA
>   076DC419 706AF48F E963A535 9E6495A3 0EDB8832 79DCB8A4 E0D5E91E
>   97D2D988 09B64C2B 7EB17CBD E7B82D07 90BF1D91 1DB71064 6AB020F2
>   F3B97148 84BE41DE 1ADAD47D 6DDDE4EB F4D4B551 83D385C7 136C9856
>   646BA8C0 FD62F97A 8A65C9EC 14015C4F 63066CD9 FA0F3D63 8D080DF5
>   3B6E20C8 4C69105E D56041E4 A2677172 3C03E4D1 4B04D447 D20D85FD
>   A50AB56B 35B5A8FA 42B2986C DBBBC9D6 ACBCF940 32D86CE3 45DF5C75
>   DCD60DCF ABD13D59 26D930AC 51DE003A C8D75180 BFD06116 21B4F4B5
>   56B3C423 CFBA9599 B8BDA50F 2802B89E 5F058808 C60CD9B2 B10BE924
>   2F6F7C87 58684C11 C1611DAB B6662D3D 76DC4190 01DB7106 98D220BC
>   EFD5102A 71B18589 06B6B51F 9FBFE4A5 E8B8D433 7807C9A2 0F00F934
>   9609A88E E10E9818 7F6A0DBB 086D3D2D 91646C97 E6635C01 6B6B51F4
>   1C6C6162 856530D8 F262004E 6C0695ED 1B01A57B 8208F4C1 F50FC457
>   65B0D9C6 12B7E950 8BBEB8EA FCB9887C 62DD1DDF 15DA2D49 8CD37CF3
>   FBD44C65 4DB26158 3AB551CE A3BC0074 D4BB30E2 4ADFA541 3DD895D7
>   A4D1C46D D3D6F4FB 4369E96A 346ED9FC AD678846 DA60B8D0 44042D73
>   33031DE5 AA0A4C5F DD0D7CC9 5005713C 270241AA BE0B1010 C90C2086
>   5768B525 206F85B3 B966D409 CE61E49F 5EDEF90E 29D9C998 B0D09822
>   C7D7A8B4 59B33D17 2EB40D81 B7BD5C3B C0BA6CAD EDB88320 9ABFB3B6
>   03B6E20C 74B1D29A EAD54739 9DD277AF 04DB2615 73DC1683 E3630B12
>   94643B84 0D6D6A3E 7A6A5AA8 E40ECF0B 9309FF9D 0A00AE27 7D079EB1
>   F00F9344 8708A3D2 1E01F268 6906C2FE F762575D 806567CB 196C3671
>   6E6B06E7 FED41B76 89D32BE0 10DA7A5A 67DD4ACC F9B9DF6F 8EBEEFF9
>   17B7BE43 60B08ED5 D6D6A3E8 A1D1937E 38D8C2C4 4FDFF252 D1BB67F1
>   A6BC5767 3FB506DD 48B2364B D80D2BDA AF0A1B4C 36034AF6 41047A60
>   DF60EFC3 A867DF55 316E8EEF 4669BE79 CB61B38C BC66831A 256FD2A0
>   5268E236 CC0C7795 BB0B4703 220216B9 5505262F C5BA3BBE B2BD0B28
>   2BB45A92 5CB36A04 C2D7FFA7 B5D0CF31 2CD99E8B 5BDEAE1D 9B64C2B0
>   EC63F226 756AA39C 026D930A 9C0906A9 EB0E363F 72076785 05005713
>   95BF4A82 E2B87A14 7BB12BAE 0CB61B38 92D28E9B E5D5BE0D 7CDCEFB7
>   0BDBDF21 86D3D2D4 F1D4E242 68DDB3F8 1FDA836E 81BE16CD F6B9265B
>   6FB077E1 18B74777 88085AE6 FF0F6A70 66063BCA 11010B5C 8F659EFF
>   F862AE69 616BFFD3 166CCF45 A00AE278 D70DD2EE 4E048354 3903B3C2
>   A7672661 D06016F7 4969474D 3E6E77DB AED16A4A D9D65ADC 40DF0B66
>   37D83BF0 A9BCAE53 DEBB9EC5 47B2CF7F 30B5FFE9 BDBDF21C CABAC28A
>   53B39330 24B4A3A6 BAD03605 CDD70693 54DE5729 23D967BF B3667A2E
>   C4614AB8 5D681B02 2A6F2B94 B40BBE37 C30C8EA1 5A05DF1B
>   2D02EF8D";\r\nvar c = 1403226680\r\nvar slt = "1fLtEZz5"\r\nvar s1 =
>   \'h\'\r\nvar s2 = \'l\'\r\nvar n = 4\r\nvar start =
>   s1.charCodeAt(0);\r\nvar end   = s2.charCodeAt(0);\r\nvar arr = new
>   Array(n);\r\nvar m = Math.pow(((end - start) + 1),n);\r\nfor (var i=0;
>   i=0;--j) {\r\nvar t = arr[j].charCodeAt(0);\r\nt++; arr[j] =
>   String.fromCharCode(t);\r\nif (arr[j].charCodeAt(0)<=end) {\r\nbreak;}
>   else { arr[j] = s1 ;}}\r\nvar chlg = arr.join(""); var str = chlg +
>   slt;\r\nvar crc = 0;\r\nvar crc = crc ^ (-1);\r\nfor( var k = 0, iTop
>   = str.length; k < iTop; k++ ){ crc = (crc >> 8) ^ ("0x" + table.substr(((crc ^ str.charCodeAt(k) ) & 0x000000FF) * 9,
>   8));}\r\ncrc =  crc ^ (-1);\r\ncrc = Math.abs(crc);\r\nif (crc ==
>   parseInt(c)){break;}}\r\ndocument.cookie = "TSe8eecf_75=" +
>   "679f30133acfc6e01dcf7ef59af22666:" + chlg + ":" + slt + ":" + crc +
>   ";Max-Age=3600;path=/";\r\ndocument.forms[0].elements[2].value=str_reverse(document.forms[0].elements[2].value)\r\ndocument.forms[0].elements[4].value=str_reverse(document.forms[0].elements[4].value)\r\ndocument.forms[0].attributes[\'action\'].value=str_reverse(document.forms[0].attributes[\'action\'].value)\r\ndocument.forms[0].submit();} '

when trying with the same url with chrom page downloads without a problem, so its not that the IP or user agent is blocked..

What could be the problem?

Comment: This requests seems to contain javascript is this the entire response?

Comment: Yes, looks like it. However this code worked fine without any kins of javascript handling up until today.

Comment: I guess they don't want you to scrape their data ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this page works is such that when a GET request is issued for the URL a javascript snippet is returned and the js snippet does a POST request to the server. See the output of http headers captured by "Live HTTP Headers" firefox extensions.

```
http://maya.tase.co.il/bursa/index.asp?view=search&group_first_level=1&company_group=3000&arg_comp=&srh_comp_lb=1349&srh_from=2013-2-2&srh_until=2013-2-12&srh_anaf=-1&srh_event=9999&is_urgent=0&srh_company_press=

GET /bursa/index.asp?view=search&group_first_level=1&company_group=3000&arg_comp=&srh_comp_lb=1349&srh_from=2013-2-2&srh_until=2013-2-12&srh_anaf=-1&srh_event=9999&is_urgent=0&srh_company_press= HTTP/1.1
Host: maya.tase.co.il
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: LBMaya=2; TS7c8b94=21efb14c7892000e308875477ef97a44a4e4ec0c353c57aa511a0278; TSe8eecf=577463c4dff39a4cd00ac387822be6f8a4e4ec0c353c57aa511a06039dbef3f4669e6cc2; ASPSESSIONIDAQRASAAB=APJODHLAKLHBLDBFFIJFBMKD; __utma=204212108.1708073596.1360658775.1360658775.1360658775.1; __utmb=204212108; __utmc=204212108; __utmz=204212108.1360658775.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); TSe8eecf_75=607adbfcad09964b707d73029eb6c75e:ywvw:I5Krl8W8:448224545; TSe8eecf_31=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

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 4323
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 12 Feb 2013 09:02:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
----------------------------------------------------------
http://maya.tase.co.il/bursa/index.asp?view=search&group_first_level=1&company_group=3000&arg_comp=&srh_comp_lb=1349&srh_from=2013-2-2&srh_until=2013-2-12&srh_anaf=-1&srh_event=9999&is_urgent=0&srh_company_press=

POST /bursa/index.asp?view=search&group_first_level=1&company_group=3000&arg_comp=&srh_comp_lb=1349&srh_from=2013-2-2&srh_until=2013-2-12&srh_anaf=-1&srh_event=9999&is_urgent=0&srh_company_press= HTTP/1.1
Host: maya.tase.co.il
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://maya.tase.co.il/bursa/index.asp?view=search&group_first_level=1&company_group=3000&arg_comp=&srh_comp_lb=1349&srh_from=2013-2-2&srh_until=2013-2-12&srh_anaf=-1&srh_event=9999&is_urgent=0&srh_company_press=
Cookie: LBMaya=2; TS7c8b94=21efb14c7892000e308875477ef97a44a4e4ec0c353c57aa511a0278; TSe8eecf=577463c4dff39a4cd00ac387822be6f8a4e4ec0c353c57aa511a06039dbef3f4669e6cc2; ASPSESSIONIDAQRASAAB=APJODHLAKLHBLDBFFIJFBMKD; __utma=204212108.1708073596.1360658775.1360658775.1360658775.1; __utmb=204212108; __utmc=204212108; __utmz=204212108.1360658775.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); TSe8eecf_75=b1977e80a3c5a7cb63469954c8ac6e05:lmnj:yjv3396F:69895458; TSe8eecf_31=52f39e84b867da063487356c8141f112a4e4ec0c353c57aa000000000000000000fe8ffe0cfdc0fd2efc81fc6ffb87fafffa28f6def59df515f4baf390ef06ede6ed08eca7ec49eba1ea0ee757e533e49ce375dff9df7dded2de56dd9ddd87d93ad895d7a8d607d5cccfdfcfb5cf5bcef4ce70ce1acc14cc0ecb3ac91cc8b3c78ec621c445c1dfbbe4bb0abaa5ba4bb331b29eb1d7b1c8b0faad85ad6bacc4ac2aabc2ab2caa83aa6da317a2b8a1739ff09f1e9eb19e5f99b7995998f6981893e8918c90238fd68f388f0b8e978e798c678991897f88d0883e826181aa80057a967a8c72dd718870276b1f6b05635461ae60015be05a4f599e53db527451cf4bc64a69481743fd42524046362734f931eb30442f5f271326cd257021cd206217eb066202cf
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 69
TSe8eecf_id=1&TSe8eecf_md=1&TSe8eecf_rf=0&TSe8eecf_ct=0&TSe8eecf_pd=0
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
X-Maya: 2
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Tue, 12 Feb 2013 09:02:45 GMT
Content-Length: 10652
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: OK, I see. so now the question is how to run the javascript snippet in python. any idea?

Comment: @WeaselFox This might be something that you could use http://blog.motane.lu/2009/06/18/pywebkitgtk-execute-javascript-from-python/

Answer (score 2):

The page may contain ajax/javascript code to load the real data. Write the output to a file and open the file with a browser/text editor.

Comment: does not work with chrome. The response has changed, previously I got a different response, without any javascript engine.

Comment: requests will not be enough. you may need selenium or an embedded browser to do this.